# NSPredicate to get maximum value below a specified value

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

I have a Core Data based table of `NSDate`s and numeric values.

I am trying to create a `NSPredicate` to get the numeric value for the maximum date which is below a given date, e.g. for DEC-31-2012, I would like to get `DEC-30-2012` or `DEC-29-2012` if this is the latest date before `DEC-31-2012`.

Unfortunately, my predicate does not work and results in a runtime crash:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest 
   fetchRequestWithEntityName:NSStringFromClass([self class])];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate 
   predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(SELF,$x,$x.date.@max <= %@)",endDate];
```

Error:

> Unable to parse the format string "SUBQUERY(SELF,$x,$x.date.@max <= %@)"

How would I need to rewrite my predicate in order to get this correct?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm sure you already got this, but you misspelled "SUBQUERY()"

Comment: Thank you, I really did miss this spelling error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following strategy should work:

- Use a predicate that fetches all objects with a date below the given date:

  ```
  NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"date < %@", endDate];
  [request setPredicate:predicate];
  ```
- Add a sort descriptor to sort the results by date *descending*, so that the last date comes first:

  ```
  NSSortDescriptor *sortDesc = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"date" ascending:NO];
  [request setSortDescriptors:@[sortDesc]];
  ```
- Set the fetch limit to one:

  ```
  [request setFetchLimit:1];
  ```

By setting the launch argument "-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 1", one can see that the filtering is done on the SQLite level:

```
SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZDATE, t0.ZNAME FROM ZENTITY t0 WHERE  t0.ZDATE < ? ORDER BY t0.ZDATE DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: This is what I am currently doing in my "old" code and it seems to be rather slow compared to a pure database-based calculation.

Comment: @AlexR: I thought that all calculations *are* done on the SQLite level. You can add "-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 1" to your apps launch arguments to see the SQLite statements and their execution time.

Answer (score 0):

Apply predicate like this

```
NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"startDate <= %@ && endDate >= %@", start, end];
```

where

`start` and `end` are `NSDate Objects` (dateRange)

`startDate` and `endDate` are keys.

Comment: Thank you, arun! How would that give the maximum date which is below is the endDate?